# Sending sensitive data through Electron’s IPC renderer

Tags: node.js, security, electron, ipc

Is Electron IPC renderer safe enough to send sensitive data through it, I want to send sensitive data from one html view to main.js in Electron. Are there any security concerns and if so, do you know how to do it more safe?
Thank you for your answers

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so. After all it is a desktop application. If someone has access to your desktop you are lost anyway.

If you want to increase security you could encode/decode your messages. However, I think you would need to build something on your own or find a framework.